# facebook desktop app C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, facebook, desktop

I am trying to build a desktop app to use facebook api and get data from friends.
Anyways I am stuck in the log in stage.
I have used some advice and made the log in to facebook with WebBrowser. It works great.
I am stuck at trying to make it give me status = Failed or success

I tried doing it like this at the end of the button_1 method

```
if (!w.DocumentText.Contains(@"<div class=""linkWrap noCount"">Messages</div>"))
    {
        w.Navigate(@"http://www.facebook.com/login.php");
        MessageBox.Show("Login error. Wrong username or password!");
    }

    else
    {
       MessageBox.Show("Logged in successfully");

    }
```

the < div class=""linkWrap noCount"">Messages< /div> is only shown while logged in so thats why I use it to see if a user is logged in

but the problem is it always gives me an error (wrong user and pass) becasue it reads it before the browser finishes to navigate to the page. I tried threads and thread sleep and even timers but it doesnt seem to work

an ideas?

here is the code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(WorkThreadFunction));
        thread.Start();

         string email = textBox1.Text;
    string password = textBox2.Text;

    // create a new browser
    WebBrowser w = new WebBrowser();
    w.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    this.Controls.Add(w); // you may add the controll to your windows forms if  you want to see what is going on
    // latter you may not chose to add the browser or you can even set it to invisible... 


    // navigate to facebook
    w.Navigate(@"http://www.facebook.com/login.php");

    // wait a little
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
    }


    HtmlElement temp=null;

    // while we find an element by id named email
    while (temp == null)
    {
        temp = w.Document.GetElementById("email");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
    }

    // once we find it place the value
    temp.SetAttribute("value", email);


    temp = null;
    // wiat till element with id pass exists
    while (temp == null)
    {
        temp = w.Document.GetElementById("pass");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
    }
    // once it exist set its value equal to passowrd
    temp.SetAttribute("value", password);

    // if you already found the last fields the button should also be there...

    var inputs = w.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");

    int counter = 0;
    bool enableClick = false;

    // iterate through all the inputs in the document
    foreach (HtmlElement btn in inputs)
    {

        try
        {
            var att = btn.GetAttribute("tabindex");
            var name = btn.GetAttribute("id");

            if (enableClick)// button to submit always has a differnt id. it should be after password textbox
            {
                btn.InvokeMember("click");
                counter++;
            }

            if (name.ToUpper().Contains("PASS") || att=="4") 
            {
                enableClick = true;  // button should be next to the password input                    
            }

            // try a max of 5 times
            if (counter > 5)
            {
                break;

            }
        }
        catch
        {


        }


                }






    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout the facebook-sharp SDK for Windows forms:

https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-winforms

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: This SDK doesn't log me in as a normal user, but only if I have an app ID and that's not what I need.. Thanks anyways

Comment: You can create a facebook app and use that for the connection. It is a simple process and I am not sure if you can do Facebook login without any app. When you are logging in to facebook using the SDK, it must request permissions as an application.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use [Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/). It uses the [OAuth protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth), [for user-authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/).

Down an code example how to get user friends with `Facebook-C#-SDK:`

```
using Facebook; //add reference to facebook dll for it work
```

declare the fields:

```
private FacebookOAuthResult result;
private FacebookOAuthClient OAuth;
```

and

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (webBrowser1.Url.AbsolutePath == "/login.php")
            {
                     // do login..      
            }

            if (FacebookOAuthResult.TryParse(e.Url, out result))
            {
                if (result.IsSuccess)
                {
                  FacebookClient fbClient = new FacebookClient(result.AccessToken);
                  dynamic friends = fbClient.Get("/me/friends"); //User friends
                  // do something.. 
                }
                else
                {
                    string errorDescription = result.ErrorDescription;
                    string errorReason = result.ErrorReason;
                    string msg = String.Format("{0} ({1})", errorReason, errorDescription);
                    MessageBox.Show(msg, "User-authentication failed!");
                }
            }
        }
```

and then for start user-authentication:

```
//.. 

    OAuth = new FacebookOAuthClient();
    OAuth.AppId = appId; // see link above,you can find how to get it
    OAuth.AppSecret = appSecret; // see link above,you can find how to get it

    Uri loginUrl = OAuth.GetLoginUrl(paramenters);
    webBrowser1.Navigate(loginUrl.AbsoluteUri);
```